# Border not surrounding anchor elements

Tags: html, css

I'm probably missing something obvious here so apologies. I'm using the below code HTML, and attempting to use CSS rule to put a border round the class "third-content-wrapper", but the border is just applied to the text and round the images as i expected. Any thoughts as to what i'm missing? I can get around it by putting a paragraph after the images, but i want to avoide if possible.  Cheers, Alex

```
<div class="third-content">

 <div class="third-content-wrapper">
    <h2> Interests </h2>
        <p> Enjoying staying active by running, circuit training and attending the gym. Enjoy playing tennis, Badminton & Table tennis. I play guitar and also enjoy landscape painting having done art at A-Level and GCSE.


  <div id="images-interests">       
    <a href="images/badminton.jpg"> <img src="images/badminton.jpg"> </a>
    <a href="images/guitar.jpg"> <img src="images/guitar.jpg"> </a>
    <a href="images/tennis.jpg"> <img src="images/tennis.jpg"> </a>
    <a href="images/painting1.jpg"> <img src="images/painting1.jpg"> </a>
    </p>
  </div>



 </div>
</div>



.third-content-wrapper{
        border: solid 2px rgba(211,211,211,0.7);
        padding: 10px 30px;

        }
```

Comment: So what exactly do you want to do here? You applied `third-content-wrapper` to a wrapping div, and not to the anchors themselves

Comment: You should close your paragraph tag first. And its not clean what you are willing to accomplish.

Comment: The paragraph is properly closed by a following `div` tag. You need to remove the closing `</p>` inside `div#images-interest` though. Check if you have something like `float: left;` defined for the anchors.

Comment: Actually, the `</p>` closing tag should be at the end of the paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

As you said: I'm using the below code HTML, and attempting to use CSS rule to put a border round the class "third-content-wrapper", but the border is just applied to the text and round the images as i expected.

I'm confused you did put the border around the third-content-wrapper like you wanted... are looking for something along the lines of this:

```css
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.third-content-wrapper {
  border: solid 2px rgba(211,211,211,0.7);
  padding: 10px 30px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="third-content">
 <div class="third-content-wrapper">
    <h2> Interests </h2>
    <p> Enjoying staying active by running, circuit training and attending the gym. Enjoy playing tennis, Badminton & Table tennis. I play guitar and also enjoy landscape painting having done art at A-Level and GCSE.<p>

    <div id="images-interests">       
      <a href="images/badminton.jpg"> <img src="images/badminton.jpg"> </a>
      <a href="images/guitar.jpg"> <img src="images/guitar.jpg"> </a>
      <a href="images/tennis.jpg"> <img src="images/tennis.jpg"> </a>
      <a href="images/painting1.jpg"> <img src="images/painting1.jpg"> </a>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Its pretty much the same result but when you go full screen its not tightly around the class. You can fiddle around with the height and width and maybe try center the div in the middle of the border. If that's what your looking for. For example:

```css
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.third-content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.third-content-wrapper {
  border: solid 2px rgba(211,211,211,0.7);
  padding: 10px 30px;
  width: 75%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="third-content">
 <div class="third-content-wrapper">
    <h2> Interests </h2>
    <p> Enjoying staying active by running, circuit training and attending the gym. Enjoy playing tennis, Badminton & Table tennis. I play guitar and also enjoy landscape painting having done art at A-Level and GCSE.<p>

    <div id="images-interests">       
      <a href="images/badminton.jpg"> <img src="images/badminton.jpg"> </a>
      <a href="images/guitar.jpg"> <img src="images/guitar.jpg"> </a>
      <a href="images/tennis.jpg"> <img src="images/tennis.jpg"> </a>
      <a href="images/painting1.jpg"> <img src="images/painting1.jpg"> </a>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Here's a link to more info on flex-box: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

The code I did for flex-box can be done in a more elegant way just to let you know :p

Comment: Thank you! I think i need to invest some time to learn flex-box! cheers